# Creating chart sdk in Metro UI using C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

Do we have any free chart sdk which works with Metro UI (Windows 8)?

Comment: By "Metro UI" do you mean on Windows 8?

Comment: do you need to use a charting library or to create it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no native controls available, I was able to port the C# wrapper over Google Charts (http://code.google.com/p/googlechartsharp/) to Metro Library. This wrapper will return the URL of the chart image which you can render on screen.